# ASP.NET Inline Global Session Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I am unable to figure out how to store a List of strings as a global variable, add to that list on button click for any unknown number of times, store that list in a session, and then properly access that session data in a separate page. I have gotten close, but have weird things occurring and my efforts to debug are doing even more unusual things.

Here is the first page script with Button1_Click() bound to OnClick of Button1:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateNums(ele, evt)
        {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                if (ele.id == 'TextBox1') {
                    var i = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
                    document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = i.slice(0, -1);
                }
                else
                {
                    var b = document.getElementById('TextBox2').value;
                    document.getElementById('TextBox2').value = b.slice(0, -1);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script runat="server">
       private static int counter = 0;
       List<string> reg = new List<string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            string[] states = { "AK","AL","AR","AS","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE","FL","GA","GU","HI","IA","ID",
            "IL","IN","KS","KY","LA","MA","MD","ME","MH","MI","MN","MO","MS","MT","NC","ND","NE","NH","NJ","NM","NV","NY",
            "OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","PW","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VA","VI","VT","WA","WI","WV","WY" };

            int b = 0;

            foreach (string i in states) 
            { 
            this.DropDownList1.Items.Add(states[b]);
            b++;
            }

            if (Session["counter"] != null)
            {
                Session.Clear();
            }
            else { counter = 0; }

        }

        protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Session["counter"] = counter;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text.Length == 0) Alert_First();
            if (TextBox2.Text.Length == 0) Alert_Second();
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "") Alert_State();
            if (TextBox4.Text.Length == 0) Alert_Password();
            if (TextBox1.Text.Length != 0 && TextBox2.Text.Length != 0 && DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "")
            {
                if (Password_Validate()) Save_Registery();
                else Alert_Password();
            }
        }

        private bool Password_Validate() 
        {
            foreach (char i in TextBox4.Text)
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(i))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void Alert_First() 
        {
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            TextBox1.Text = "A value is required";
        }
        private void Alert_Second()
        {
            TextBox2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            TextBox2.Text = "A value is required";
        }
        private void Alert_State()
        {
            DropDownList1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        private void Alert_Password()
        {
            TextBox4.BackColor = Color.Red;
            TextBox4.Text = "A value is required with at least one numeric value";
        }
        private void Save_Registery() 
        {
           if (Session["regList"] != null)
            {
            reg.AddRange((List<string>)Session["regList"]);
             }
            reg.Add(TextBox1.Text);
            reg.Add(TextBox2.Text);
            reg.Add(DropDownList1.Text);
            reg.Add(TextBox4.Text);
            Session["regList"] = reg;
            TextBox3.Text = counter.ToString();
            counter++;
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach(string i in reg)
               {
                       TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text + reg[0].ToString();
                       count++;
               }
        }

</script>

</head>

<body style="margin:auto; max-width:300px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="float:left; max-width:200px;" >
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="First Name: "></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last Name: "></asp:Label>
        <br /> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="State"></asp:Label>
        <br /> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Password: "></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"  />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="All Fields are Required" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    </div>
 <a href="Results.aspx" style="">
        <div>
            <p>
            Results
            </p>
        </div>
</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the second page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script runat="server">

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            int counter = Convert.ToInt16(Session["counter"]);
            Repeater1.DataSource = (List<string>)Session["regList"];
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }

    </script>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">   
        <div>
            <%= Session["counter"] %>
        </div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>

            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# Container.DataItem %>
                    </td>


                </tr>

            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
            </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This outputs only the LAST set of data that I entered via the previous page. The count I added to help debug tells me that there is only 3 values in my session variable of "regList". My question is why is my data getting overwritten every time the Button1_Click() is fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pageload event of the first page, you are resetting the seesion list by reg,

Session["regList"] = reg;

which by that time the reg is an empty list, and it becomes an issue

Comment: I added `reg.AddRange((List<string>)Session["regList"]);` to the beginning of Button1_Click and `Session["regList"] = reg;` to be the last thing executed in the method. It is still only storing the last 3 entries.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code and see if everything is what you expected. Also, can you post your updated code there?

Comment: Also, how do you 'jump' from the first page to the second one? by another button click or just open that in another tab of the browser or ...?

Comment: I replaced the original code with my current files. Thanks for taking the time to look at it. As far as debugging see my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038456/asp-net-inline-coding-fundamental-questions) on why I am having difficulty with this.

Comment: in your pageload event of the first page, you set the Session["regList"] = reg; by that time reg is an empty list, that is why it is getting reset everytime. You shouldn't do that if you want to keep a history of the reg.

Comment: Yes, I put that there because if I do not I get an System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: I removed session initialization in the page load event and added a check to make sure that the session is not null, unfortunately it is still only displaying the last session entered. I will update the code to reflect my changes.

Comment: If that is the issue, you need to check if that has been set already. But you cannot set that everytime. Do something like that instead, if (Session["regList"] == null)
            {Session["regList"] = new List<string>();}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38134/discussion-between-justin-and-stay-foolish)